# Batch file to find specific services that are not running

Tags: windows, batch

I have a set of services that I need to check to see if they are running or not.

Some have set names, i.e. (ServiceX, ServiceY)

The rest all start with a prefix.

so far I have

`sc query | find "NAME" | find "PREFIX"`

this finds all the services with that prefix but doesnt show me if they are running or not.

I would like it to show me the names of all services that are not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WMI can get you the status of each service, and wmic is a command-line way to query WMI. For example, to find services with "net" in the display name and a state of not running, you would use

```
wmic service where (displayname like '%net%' and state != 'running') get displayname,name,state
```